# Seeding database rails belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, seed

I'm trying to seed a database with 4 users.  Each User has has_one profile and has_many todo_lists.
User model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todo_lists, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :todo_items, through: :todo_lists, source: :todo_items
end
```

Here is my seed file

```
User.destroy_all

user_list = [
  ["Carly", "Fiorina", "female", 1954],
  ["Donald", "Trump", "male", 1946],
  ["Ben", "Carson", "male", 1951],
  ["Hillary", "Clinton", "female", 1947]
]

user_list.each do |fname, lname, gender, byear|
    {
        User.create!(username: lname, password_digest: "xyz")
        User.profile.create! (first_name: fname, last_name: lname, gender: gender, birth_year: byear )
        User.todo_list.create!(list_name: "temp", list_due_date: 1.year.from_now); 
    }
end
```

I'm getting the error unexpected tLABEL pointing to username: lname.  My migration to create the user table is :

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use brackets in a do-end block. Try this:

```
user_list.each do |fname, lname, gender, byear|
  user = User.create!(username: lname, password_digest: "xyz")
  user.create_profile!(first_name: fname, last_name: lname, gender: gender, birth_year: byear )
  user.todo_lists.create!(list_name: "temp", list_due_date: 1.year.from_now); 
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is true thanks for the catch.  I think the problem may be that I can't create a profile through a user.  Maybe I have to create a profile and then assign it to a user?

Comment: You need to create the profile and todo_lists off the user instance, rather than the user class. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Keep in mind that your Profile and TodoList models should have a foreign key linking them back to user.

Comment: Now I get a NoMethodError undefined method create!

Comment: @leenyburger my mistake! `profile.create` doesn't work because it's a has_one relationship, so there's no profile to call create on. the correct method is `create_profile!` and i've changed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yes!  Appreciate the help.  If I understand correctly I can't call user.profile.create because it's a has_one but I can call user.todo_lists.create because it's a has_many.